# Formula for volume of liquid residue in containers after pouring

Tags: fluid-dynamics, surface-tension, viscosity, volume

When trying to empty the filled containers by pouring, we will find that this is impossible to reach the "real empty" as some residual liquid should exist in the containers. Have some mathematical formulae found about determining the exact volume (maybe depends on the material and the shape of the containers, nature of the liquid, etc)?

Comment: You're right, it "depends on the material and the shape of the containers, nature of the liquid, etc.", so it's too broad.